# python script searching for a string in files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: python

I have a python script that searches for a string in files in a directory and its subdirectories.

---

```
import os
from sys import argv

print(argv)

searchStr = argv[1]

def searchDir(dirCurrent):

    try:
        main_directory = os.listdir(dirCurrent)

        for item in main_directory:

            item_path = os.path.join(dirCurrent, item)
            if os.path.isdir(item_path) == True:
                searchDir(item_path)
            else: 
                f = open(item_path, 'r')
                file_contents = f.read()
                if searchStr in file_contents:
                    print("found in file " + item_path)     
    except:
        print("Unable to access the directory " + dirCurrent)

searchDir("C:\\Users\\myname-adm\\Documents")
```

---

It runs, but when it encounters folders without read permissions, the script stops.  How can I modify it so it can keep on searching while skipping the folders without read access?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Narrow your try/except so that it is inside the loop.

Comment: When you handle exception skip that folder.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import os from sys import argv

print(argv)

searchStr = argv[1]

def searchDir(dirCurrent):

        main_directory = os.listdir(dirCurrent)

        for item in main_directory:
            try:
                item_path = os.path.join(dirCurrent, item)
                if os.path.isdir(item_path) == True:
                    searchDir(item_path)
                else: 
                    f = open(item_path, 'r')
                    file_contents = f.read()
                    if searchStr in file_contents:
                        print("found in file " + item_path)     
            except:
                print("Unable to access the directory " + dirCurrent)

searchDir("C:\\Users\\myname-adm\\Documents")
```